# Transform differents element into array in only one array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to display multiple elements in a single array. (See example)

But I do not know how to do it ...

Thanks for your help

I display my script:

```
****Du code******

var color = [];
var risk = []; 
if(Operational.length == group.name.length){
  color = "green";
  risk = "Operational";
  console.log(group.name);
  // toto
  // tata
  // titi
}

if(Test.length > 0){
  color = "";
  risk = "";
}

 if(PartialOutage.length > 0){
   color = "orange"
   risk = "Partial";
 }

 if(MajorOutage.length > 0){
   color = "red";
   risk = "Major ";
 }
  var Group = new Array(color,risk,group.name);     
   Groups.push(Group);
   Groups.sort();
 }
});          
console.log(Groups);
}

**** Du code *****
```

Actual result :

```
[ [ 'green', 'Operational', 'toto' ],
[ 'green', 'Operational', 'tata' ],
[ 'green', 'Operational', 'titi' ],
[ 'orange', 'Partial', 'test' ],
[ 'red', 'Major ', 'test2' ] ]
```

Expected result  :

```
[ [ 'green', 'Operational', 'toto,tata,titi' ],
[ 'orange', 'Partial', 'test' ],
[ 'red', 'Major ', 'test2' ] ]
```

Comment: Because there seem to be a direct relation between your risks and a color, you seem to have only 3 arrays here every time, why not have 3 named vars for these arrays `operational`, `partial` and `major`, and add items to them instead of creating an anonymous array each time?

Comment: Your question is missing the loop. Also it is missing the logic to combine by name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this out.Recreate the final array value as you expected format using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

1. Push the first one child array into New Array `a`
2. Then loop the each `b` child array with newly created array `a`
3. Used `forloop` for break the loop
4. if child array value exist in new array `a` .Then Merge two array and filter the duplicate  `//Check the comments in snippet`

```js
var a = [
  ['green', 'Operational', 'toto'],
  ['green', 'Operational', 'tata'],
  ['green', 'Operational', 'titi'],
  ['orange', 'Partial', 'test'],
  ['red', 'Major ', 'test2']
];

a = a.reduce(function(a, b) {
  for (var i = 0; i <= b.length; i++) {
    var brk = false;
    var check = true;
    if (a.length > 0) {
      a.forEach(function(k, ind) {
        if (k.indexOf(b[i]) > -1) { //if contains same arg
          k = k.concat(b); //join two array
          var j = k.filter((l,n)=> k.filter(m=> m == l).length == 1).filter(o=>o)
          a[ind] = k.filter((l, n) => k.indexOf(l) != n); // filter duplicate
          a[ind].push(j.join(','))
          brk = true; //then break the statement
          check = true;
        } else {
          check = false; //its not contain any arg direct push child into new array
        }
      })
      if (brk) {
        break;
      }
      if (!check) {
        a.push(b)
      }
    } else {
      a.push(b);
    }
  }
  return a // recreated new array return
}, []);

console.log(a);
```

Comment: I think the OP should learn to store the data properly in variables rather than post-process it with complex solutions they might not really understand. Still a valid answer though..

Comment: i already read your comment. I just transform result to expected result that's all

Comment: Thanks for your help but it's possible to add toto tata and titi in one element. (Like this : "toto,tata,titi"